# question about the conditions on the weak derivative of periodic function

Tags: analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a periodic, say  with the period 1, and locally integrable function.

Assume that $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a weak derivative of $f$ of order $k$, that is $g$ is also locally integrable and satisfies condition
$$
\int f D^k \phi  dx=(-1)^k\int g \phi dx
$$
for all smooth functions $\phi : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ with compact supports.

My question is if we can replace in this condition "for all smooth functions $\phi : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ with compact supports" by

**for all smooth functions $\phi : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ with compact supports contained in $(0,1)$**

or by

**for all smooth $1$-periodic functions $\phi : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$**.

Comment: If $\phi$ is smooth with compact support $supp(\phi)=[a,b]$, can you find a way to produce a smooth $\psi$ with support equal to $[0,1]$ out of $\phi$?